# mysql group by week on two years

Tags: php, mysql

Hi im writing a query for get results for a area chart.i have datas for two years. i use mysql group by date for get daily results, but when i use group by week icannot find a way to seperate two years weekly datas becoz it returns with week numbers like 4,5

my code is

```
     $results=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rate) as rate, week(rdate) as rdate 
    FROM cpustats 
    WHERE server_id='$server_id' 
    GROUP BY week(rdate)") or die(mysql_error());
    $data3='';
    $data4='';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        //one day has lots of records i devide that for get average
       $rk=mysql_query("SELECT rate as rdate FROM cpustats 
    WHERE server_id='$server_id' 
    AND week(rdate)='".$row['rdate']."'") or die(mysql_error());
       $nr=mysql_num_rows($rk);
       //here has issue which shows sum of two years same week data
       $usage=round($row['rate']/$nr,2);

       //tfunction return start and end of week by passing week number
       $week=getStartAndEndDate($row['rdate']);

       $data3[] = "'".$week."'";
       $data4[] = "$usage";

}
```

can anyone help me to get seperate weekly datas for two years pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add the group by with year so it will group the results week and year wise

```
SELECT 
SUM(rate) as rate,
WEEK(rdate) as rdate ,
YEAR(rdate) as rdate_year
FROM cpustats 
WHERE server_id='$server_id' 
GROUP BY YEAR(rdate),WEEK(rdate)
```